# How to save a list under a name chosen from combox so that it can be opened by pickle after that name?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, pickle

I made some kind of to-do-list with a combox, where you can chose a day of a week. How to save such list with name seleted from this box? And also how to load it back by this name?

```
def load_tasks():
    try:
        tasks = pickle.load(open("tasks.dat", "rb"))
        listbox_tasks.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        for task in tasks:
            listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, task)
    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Warning!", message="Cannot find tasks.dat.")

def save_tasks():
    tasks = listbox_tasks.get(0, listbox_tasks.size())
    pickle.dump(tasks, open("tasks.dat", "wb"))
```

Comment: What part of what you want to do is giving you a problem?

Comment: I do not know how to make the name of the saved list dependent on the selected one

Comment: Sorry that's still unclear. Do you mean the file name that the list will be saved under? If not I suggest you add some sample code to your question to clarify what you mean.

Comment: def load_tasks():
    try:
        tasks = pickle.load(open("tasks.dat", "rb"))
        listbox_tasks.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        for task in tasks:
            listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, task)
    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Warning!", message="Cannot find tasks.dat.")

def save_tasks():
    tasks = listbox_tasks.get(0, listbox_tasks.size())
    pickle.dump(tasks, open("tasks.dat", "wb"))

And yes, i mean file name the list will be saved under. Instead of “tasks.dat” I want to named it automatically by name selected from combobox

Comment: Which will be monday etc

Comment: but I don't know how to connect it to automatically connect to selected day of the week

Comment: Can't you just use the name they selected in the `Combobox` as the name of the pickle file? e.g. Instead of hardcoding `"tasks.dat"`.

Comment: Then i will have to do 7 of it, one for each day

Comment: the whole code is that I choose the day of the week from the combobox, and I make a list of tasks for that day Which I want to save with, for example, the name Monday, if it is for Monday.  and I want the tasks to be saved under this name, depending on which day of the week I choose, because thanks to the load function I can restore lists from a specific day, also after selecting a specific day from the combobox and further modifying them

Comment: Only one item can be selected at a time in a `Combobox`, like `"Monday"`, so you use that plus `".dat"` as the filename. You can get the current `Combobox` selection by calling its `.get()` method. i.e. something like `dayofweek = mycombobox.get()`.

Comment: The point is that, for example, I make a plan for Monday, save it as Monday and then change the day and make a plan for, for example, Tuesday.  if I want to recreate the plan from Monday, I set Monday in combobox again and click the option load, and it automatically searches by the name of the day.

Comment: What I am suggesting is, after the combobox has been set to e.g. `Monday`, just do `filename = combobox.get() + ".dat"`, then you can read the contents of the proper file with `pickle.load(open(filename, "rb"))`. To get all 7 days, ignore the combobox and just loop over the seven possible filenames.

Comment: finally i made it little different but thanks for help!!

Comment: Glad to hear that. You're welcome. To help others, you might want to post what you did as an answer (which is allowed here).